# Beginner: Adding x number of widgets to layout

Tags: python, kivy

Really easy I'm sure but I'm learning Python & kivy (as a hobbyist not professional).

I have made my first 'complex' kivy layout, and am now attempting to add python code to it, and *I am fundamentally mis-understanding some things*. I am keeping it all organised in seperate files where possible.

**1. Within a GridLayout I have a ScrollView. All I want is to be able to add 'x' number of buttons to the ScrollView in it's python class.**

all relavent files ('...' indicating I have trimmed to only the relevant parts)

**seatingmanager.py:**

```
...
Builder.load_file('timescroll.kv')
...
class SeatingManager(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class SeatingManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SeatingManager()
```

**seatingmanager.kv:**

```
<SeatingManager> 
    ...
    AnchorLayout:
        ...
        GridLayout:
            ...
            TimeScroll:
                size_hint: None None
                height: 50
                width: 500
```

**2. This is creating an instance of the TimeScroll class? This is where to add specific attributes to this instance?**

timescroll.kv:

```
#:import timescroll timescroll

<TimeScroll>
```

**3. This is where I can add attributes to all TimeScroll instances? If I am not adding any is this file necessary (other than importing timescroll.py)?**

**timescroll.py:**(where I presume my problems lay)

```
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TimeScroll(ScrollView):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_x=None,width=1500)
        for i in range(10):
            btn = ToggleButton(text=str(i), group='timeHeaders')
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        self.add_widget(layout)
        return layout
```

**4. Is the build method automatically called when an instance of this class is created? If not, why is it called automatically in the first file?**

**5. This code doesn't work, simply leaves the ScrollView blank, so I presume I am adding the BoxLayout to the ScrollView incorrectly or the build method isn't automatically called.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4. Is the build method automatically called when an instance of this class is created? If not, why is it called automatically in the first file?

The build method is never called for widgets, unless you do so yourself. You should use the `__init__` method, as per normal python convention (and don't forget to call `super`).

The App class has a build method that is called to start the user's own code, but the App is not a widget, and this is the only place kivy will automatically run a build method.

Comment: I actually initially started off with `__init__` but couldn't get it to work. I did not call the `super`, and left `**kwargs` out (and removed the meaningless `return`) so I guess a few things ended me up here. Also, something really simple like "App is not a widget" is very helpful for a massive newbie :-) Have marked as best solution as it got me working, but still a little sentence for my individual questions would be helpful for my understanding. Thank you.